# How to access data from object which is in JSON format

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    { username: 'mn_admin',
      details:
              [ { appName: 'node',
                  pid: 5336,
                  starttime: '/Date(1509945756467)/',
                  endtime: '/Date(1509945868200)/',
                  appusage: 2,
                  username: 'mn_admin' } ] }
```

This is my data in JSON format.
How do I access appName in it? 
I am using MEAN stack
Also, I have tried to push the entire data into an array, but it didn't work.
I tried to access data.details but that said its an undefined object.
Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you really have your data as JSON (string !) you first have to parse it using `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 1):

if it's object, you can simply access it as `myObj.details[0].appName`. If not, you will have to parse it `const myObj = JSON.parse(jsonString)` first and then use it like above.